# How to give permissions for the application for all users which was created in azure apps portal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, permissions, azure-active-directory

I have created an app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com portal with name GroupsApp  and I have given couple of permissions as below:
[image]
I have created client id and secret to use in my application. I am using asp.net MVC  (with 4.5.1 .net framework) web application.

I am getting some groups info and displaying on the screen. If I am logged with my account it is working fine. But if I logged in as another user then it is giving me issue as below:

[image]

I have formatted url as below: https://login.microsoftonline.com/948894dc-c0e2-43e5-a7e6-1d21dd183c9d/oauth2/authorize?client_id=75acb700-e675-4dc4-9deb-d3f68f6911a1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:34280&prompt=admin_consent and trying to granted the permission. Here I have logged in as admin and given permissions.

[image]

Now if I check with normal user same issue is happening.

How should I give the permissions to this application.

I am not able to find any option to approve the permissions from the Azure portal.

Comment: Same issue? It still requires admin consent?   Indeed, you need to do permission grant for twice, once is admin consent, the other one is user consent. Because `User.Read` needs user consent. After doing admin consent, when you use a normal user , you still need to do consent with user consent.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I check with normal user same issue is happening.
>
> How should I give the permissions to this application.
>
> I am not able to find any option to approve the permissions from the Azure portal.

I could encounter the same issue according to your settings. I assumed that you may hit the [Admin-restricted scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#admin-restricted-scopes) of AAD v2.0 as follows:

> Some high-privilege permissions in the Microsoft ecosystem can be set to admin-restricted. Examples of these kinds of scopes include the following permissions:
>
> - Read an organization's directory data by using `Directory.Read`
> - Write data to an organization's directory by using `Directory.ReadWrite`
> - Read security groups in an organization's directory by using `Groups.Read.All`
>
> Although a consumer user might grant an application access to this kind of data, organizational users are restricted from granting access to the same set of sensitive company data. If your application requests access to one of these permissions from an organizational user, the user receives an error message that says they are not authorized to consent to your app's permissions.

You could [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) and follow this [Build an app with admin restricted scopes using the v2.0 endpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2) github code sample to ensure your app can gather permissions for all users in a tenant, including admin-restricted scopes.

Comment: I will give a try and let you know

Comment: actually the problem here is, even if I approve the permissions with administrator account, when I login as normal user it is still asking the admin consent. Is it not possible to apply the approved permissions for all users?